# GitHub fetch update the local repository but code results still for old code

Tags: eclipse, github, fetch

I fetch the code from GitHub. The local repository is updated and same as one on the upstream. But when I run the code it brings the results of code before update? I am using git on eclipse

Comment: you likely need to do a `pull`, fetch will not update local branches see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you be more specific?  What have you tried for example.

Answer (score 0):

When you have connected to a remote repository and you want the current files from the repo, you would do a `pull`.

For example, you have repository named "ClueGameDevelopment", and you want files from the "dev" branch, you would do:
`git pull ClueGameDevelopment dev`.

This would put all of the current files from the remote repository into your local repository.

Answer (score 0):

`git fetch` is used for fetch branch on your local repository, but if you want to update your code with the latest, you'd do a pull in your branch. `git pull <remote repository> <branch>`. If you use `git fetch`, you'll see new branches on your local repository.